# R: Package ROCR for plotting ROC curve

Tags: r, roc

I'm using the package `ROCR` in order to plot the ROC curve of an binary classification.
The way I'm doing this is like proposed here:

```
data(ROCR.simple)
df <- data.frame(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction(df$predictions, df$labels)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
```

[image]

My assumption is that the colored scale on the right shows the threshold that is used to assign the predictions of the binary models to either 0 or 1. Then the graph shows the appropriate TPR and FPR, correct?

Comment: The [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/ROCR.pdf) explains what's going on here. Look at page 8

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is the question exactly?